# Designing a Turing machine for Binary Multiplication

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I need help designing a turing machine that will compute the following

$$f(x,y) = x\times y$$

How to approach this problem in binary base? This is a assignment so I don't want anyone to solve it for me because I want to do it myself, I just need a little help to design a turing machine for this problem.

I tried to make a logic, which is

1. First we have to decrement $Y$, until zero.
2. With each decrement we have to add $X$ to $X$, but I don't know how.

I can't solve any further.

Comment: Are you allowed to use multiple tapes, or to invoke the theorem that says that a multitape machine is equivalent to a single-tape machine?  You can keep $x$ on one tape, $y$ on a second tape, and the result, initially 0, in the third tape.  Then repeatedly decrement $y$ and add $x$  to the number on the third tape, until the second tape reaches 0.

Comment: @MJD I have to design a Standard Turing Machine, which allows only one tape and head.

Comment: That's a big project. You'll need to write a subroutine library, with subroutines for copying numerals from one part of the tape to another, testing numerals for zero-ness, adding numbers, and decrementing numbers, and you'll need a method for turning subroutine calls into state transitions.

Comment: But you can probably manage the tape more easily by having $x$, then a special marker, then $y$, then another special marker, then a copy of $x$, another special marker, and then the accumulator.  None of the four pieces needs to move around. Of the four pieces, the accumulator is the only one that increases, and it can expand into the unbounded empty space on the tape.  I would put the least significant bit closest to the end of the tape, with increasing bits farther away; that way you don't need to copy the entire accumulator when it gets bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a good plan -- except you don't want to add $x$ to $x$; you want to add $x$ to a separate counter that starts at $0$.

Do you already have a machine for addition with the number representation you use (which preserves one of the operands on the tape and increases the other destructively)? Otherwise start by making that.

---

Alternatively if you're representing the integers in base-2 you could replicate the usual long multiplication algorithm:

```
Set T=0
While X != 0:
   If the lowest bit of X is 1:
      Set T=T+Y
   End if
   Remove the lowest bit from X
   Append a 0 bit at the end low of Y
End while
The result is in T
```

This may not even be more complex to program, and will run faster (though *that* is typically not a relevant consideration when we talk about Turing machines. It might be a relevant difference here because it is more than a polynomial difference).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have two machines. For Addition and for Subtraction. In addition of two binary number I simply decrement Y then I increment X until Y becomes zero.

Comment: @Aniq: Then you need to start by finding an addition procedure that leaves one of the operands intact after it completes. If everything else fails you could start by simply copying that operand.

Comment: @Aniq The first option (yours) is not going to be polynomially equivalent to the long multiplication. To decrease a binary number of size n, one by one, to zero it requires $2^n$ steps. On the other hand long multiplication only requires at most $n$ additions of tranlations of $Y$ to itself.